# How to import bookmarks from Chrome or Safari into Opera 19 for OS X?

Tags: macos, browser, bookmarks, opera

I’ve just installed Opera 19 on OS X Mountain Lion and I don’t find how to import my Bookmarks from Safari or Chrome. On Windows menu the voice “Import Bookmarks” is deactivated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The migration from other browsers to Opera is not ideal. This will hopefully improve soon, but in the meantime some manual work is required.

To export from Safari, open the `File: Export Bookmarks` menu. The resulting HTML file can be opened directly in Opera as a kind of portal page with all your bookmarks. The same method can be used from Firefox and Chrome.

You then have three options:

1. Open the HTML page and drag each link from these HTML pages onto the bookmarks bar or Speed Dial
2. Install the [Bookmarks Manager extension](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/bookmarks-manager/) and use it to manage your bookmarks. It can import directly from the exported HTML files.
3. Import the HTML files into Chrome. Move all the bookmarks to the Bookmarks bar in Chrome using the Bookmarks Manager. Then manually copy the `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks` file to `~/Library/Application Support/com.operasoftware.Opera/Bookmarks` (quit both apps first!)

Not ideal, but all methods will get your bookmarks into Opera.

Hope these methods can be an acceptable. I hope that by the time others find this post using a search-engine, there will be a more user-friendly approach available.

Good luck!

*Disclaimer: I am an employee of Opera Software, however, this comment represents only my own views and whatnot.*

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is for Windows, have not tried this on OSX.

Opera 18/19 doesn't have a "Manage Bookmarks" option at this point and thus you cannot easily from within opera import your bookmarks.

Since the reboot of the Opera browser which now is based on Chrome you will have to do this manually.

They are now storing the Bookmarks in a db-file located at `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable` in a file called `bookmarks`

I do not know if this is possible to import bookmarks at this time at all. I did manage to edit in new bookmarks in this file how ever. I just copy pasted on bookmark, then changed "name" and "url".

The "bookmark"-code looks like this:

```
{
   "checksum": "bf09e07c5302ee15844dafbeaa57513a",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "children": [ {
               "date_added": "13036440856757495",
               "date_last_visit": "0",
               "description": "",
               "guid": "4750048B-1349-420F-B8FA-286EF2E917C7",
               "id": "3",
               "name": "Where are the bookmarks in Opera 18? - Opera browser - Opera Community",
               "nickname": "",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1789322"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13036441355489304",
               "date_last_visit": "0",
               "description": "",
               "guid": "63F6728C-B8CA-49DD-90F1-A6CCAF4BCFA0",
               "id": "4",
               "name": "facebook",
               "nickname": "",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13036441355489304",
               "date_last_visit": "0",
               "description": "",
               "guid": "63F6728C-B8CA-49DD-90F1-A6CCAF4BCFA0",
               "id": "4",
               "name": "Google",
               "nickname": "",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "https://www.google.se/"
            }, {
               "date_added": "13036441418005285",
               "date_last_visit": "0",
               "description": "",
               "guid": "EDA1AF94-DDE0-4D5D-996D-5851A7E2F9D3",
               "id": "7",
               "name": "How to import bookmarks from Chrome or Safari into Opera 19 for OSX? - Super User",
               "nickname": "",
               "type": "url",
               "url": "http://superuser.com/questions/714480/how-to-import-bookmarks-from-chrome-or-safari-into-opera-19-for-osx"
            } ],
            "date_added": "13036440853441495",
            "date_modified": "13036441418005285",
            "description": "",
            "guid": "5D44B413-AF8F-40CC-8A19-5EC228479516",
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Test",
            "type": "folder"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13036440645256151",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "description": "",
         "guid": "739DAED2-A313-4346-837C-A2E0F296DD67",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Bookmarks bar",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13036440645256151",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "description": "",
         "guid": "4750522C-8EBE-41AD-A6F0-84158E73B6BE",
         "id": "5",
         "name": "Other bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13036440645256151",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "description": "",
         "guid": "4749DD7D-7FDB-40F9-BD91-19BE53571935",
         "id": "6",
         "name": "Mobile bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

More on the latest version of Opera: http://betanews.com/2014/01/28/opera-19-adds-bookmarks-bar-hardcore-mode/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find that file on OSX..

Answer (score -1):

**I've located a different way to do this.**

You can install Opera 12, from there you can export by doing: `Go to Bookmarks → Manage bookmarks → File → Export as HTML and save.` this exports bookmarks as a Netscape-format HTML file.

When you've done this you can import that file with an extension called Bookmark Manager which you can find here: https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/bookmarks-manager/?display=en

I am not sure if this is also a Windows only solution, but seems easier than the previous suggestion. I know that there are some OSX versions of Opera which has `Export bookmarks as HTML...` option.